# Filling in dataframe values using row & column names

Tags: r

I have 2 dataframes. The first is an "empty grid" df using the row and column names for the size of the grid. The second dataframe has the value that needs to be filled into the empty grid with the row and column names as separate values in 2 different columns. Is there a way to check and fill the empty grid with the value of the second dataframe? I provided a visual outcome of what I need help with.

[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMMWX.png)

Ive tried a nested for loop but run into checking colnames/rownames and then changing the values.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the example shown in your image

`for(i in 1:nrow(df2)){ df1[df2[i, 2], df2[i, 3]] <- df2[i, 1] }` 
this will convert your empty dataframe 'df1' to the desired df.